# How to use href with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am developing a pdf download form from a drupal api, the pdfs are mapped within the options of a select, when I select a pdf when I hit the download button it has to open the link where the pdf is located and from there it can be downloaded. I picked up the value of the selected option and put a tag to redirect the page to the address where the pdf is, but it does not let me use the href, it gives me the following error: The expected type comes from property 'href' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes, HTMLAnchorElement>', how can I fix this error. Or maybe there is another way to do it without the href?

```
import React from 'react'
import { forwardRef, AnchorHTMLAttributes, HTMLAttributes} from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { getDocument } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import { Document } from '@icofcv/common';

type AnchorProps = AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>


export function Manuals () {

    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState<Document[]>([]);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
    const ref = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState (false)

    const fetchDocuments = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        getDocument().then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            setDocuments(response);
            setIsLoading(false)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        
        fetchDocuments();
    }, []);

    return(
        <>
        <div className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 md:p-6">
            <h1 className="pb-3 font-medium">Manuales de Estándares</h1>
            <div className="card-body py-2 md:px-12 mx-auto w-100">
                <p className="text-neutral-600 text-sm mb-2">Manual de estándares de la práctica de la Fisioterapia en Centros Sanitarios</p>
                <button className="btn bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white px-8 w-40" type="button">Descargar</button>
                <p className="text-neutral-600 text-sm font-bold my-2">Desde el siguiente formulario podrá descargar los anexos del manual, se han clasificado en 2 grupos para una mejor búsqueda.</p>
               
                <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-end justify-between my-4">
                    <div className="relative z-0 w-full group">
                   
                        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 mb-2">Anexos Estándares*</label>
                       
                        <select  onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} id="" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5">
                        <option  selected>Seleccione Anexo I</option>
                        {documents.map(docu => (
                        <>
                            
                            <option  key={docu.id} selected>{docu.contentUrl}</option>
                           
                           
                             </>
                             
                         ))}
                          
                        </select>
                    </div> 
                    <a ref={ref} href={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { const newValue = e.currentTarget.value;setInputValue(newValue)}}></a>
                   
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-end justify-between my-4">
                    <div className="relative z-0 w-full group">
                        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 mb-2">Anexos Estándares*</label>
                        <select id="" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5">
                            <option selected>Seleccione Anexo II</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white px-8 ml-4 w-full md:w-40 my-2 md:my-0" type="button">Descargar</button>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-end justify-between my-4">
                    <div className="relative z-0 w-full group">
                        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 mb-2">Anexos Estándares*</label>
                        <select id="" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5">
                            <option selected>Seleccione Anexo III</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white px-8 ml-4 w-full md:w-40 my-2 md:my-0" type="button">Descargar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is a link and the `href` is the `string` of the URL that you are linking to.  An `href` cannot be a function.  If you need a function, you can use a different prop such as `onClick`.

> when I select a pdf when I hit the download button it has to open the link where the pdf is located and from there it can be downloaded. I picked up the value of the selected option and put a tag to redirect the page to the address where the pdf is

It looks like you are trying to have a "Descargar" ("Download") button that will the open the currently selected PDF URL in a new window.

You don't need refs for this because you already have the selected document URL in your `inputValue` state.

#### Using `onClick`

One way to set this up is to use an `onClick` handler of the `<button>` which can execute any code that you want.  You can call [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and use `"_blank"` to open in a new window.  We can disable the button if no document has been selected.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="anexo-i">
      Anexos Estándares*
    </label>

    <select
      onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      value={inputValue}
      name="anexo-i"
      id="anexo-i"
    >
      <option value="">Seleccione Anexo I</option>
      {documents.map((docu) => (
          <option key={docu.id} value={docu.contentUrl}>
            {docu.name}
          </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </div>

  <button
    type="button"
    disabled={!inputValue}
    onClick={() => window.open(inputValue, '_blank')}
  >
    Descargar
  </button>
</div>
```

#### Using `href`

You can use an `<a>` element to handle the downloading.  You could open the PDF in a new window with `target="_blank"` but you can also make use of the [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) of the `<a>` element.

An `<a>` element can also have an `onClick` handler to execute any code.  You can call [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in your custom code to prevent navigating to the URL and use your own handling instead.  Here I am using the `onClick` to handle the "disabled" behavior.  You'll probably want to change the styling when it is disabled as well, since the `<a>` does not have the same built-in disabled behavior as the `<button>`.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="anexo-i">
      Anexos Estándares*
    </label>

    <select
      onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      value={inputValue}
      name="anexo-i"
      id="anexo-i"
    >
      <option value="">Seleccione Anexo I</option>
      {documents.map((docu) => (
        <option key={docu.id} value={docu.contentUrl}>
          {docu.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </div>

  <a
    className={
      inputValue ? "your regular styles" : "your disabled styles"
    }
    role="button"
    href={inputValue}
    target="_blank"
    onClick={(e) => {
      if (!inputValue) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Please select a file");
      }
      // otherwise, do the default behavior
    }}
  >
    Descargar
  </a>
</div>
```

[CodeSandbox with both approches.](https://codesandbox.io/s/download-selected-file-yx9u0w?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: thank you very much, both answers have been very helpful.